# Recover deleted files that were stored in userprofile with profile encryption on Windows having only hard drive

Tags: data-recovery

A friend of mine gave me physical hard disc that contained some files in `My documents` that were deleted (by `Move to Trash` -> then `Empty Trash`) and wanted me to recover them if possible.

I've plug in drive via external USB-to-SATA converter and run `Recuva` on it. It found a lot of encrypted files in user profile directory, along with some non-encrypted that were deleted from other locations (like `C:\`). I asked my friend, but she claims she never encrypted drive, so I believe this is just User Profile directory being encrypted by Windows.

I don't have access to previous PC, it was already sold out. What I want to do now is to run `sysprep`-like tool to wipe motherboard drivers, then plug-in and launch OS directly from drive on my PC. This present the risk of data being overwritten, but it was deemed acceptable by the friend. The question is: after I log in into her account on OS, will `Recuva` be able to restore user profile files? It should have access to encryption keys defined in user profile, should it not?

Is there any other way to recover files? The files are not that important to involve external recovery company, as recovery cost would vastly exceed gain.

Comment: If you don't have access to the private key.  What you want is not possible.  The files are encrypted because EFS was being used.

Comment: @Ramhound Where the private key is located?

Comment: If the user backed it up, they would know, if they don't know it likely wasn't backed up.  You understand sysprep does make changes right, it basically installs the OS, so data will be overwritten.

Comment: @Ramhound The valid OS is still present, I just don't have means to boot it since there will be serious hardware mismatch. Is there a way to retrieve the private key?

Comment: No; there isn't not at this point

Comment: @Ramhound But are you sure sysprep will wipe out private key? It leaves user profile intact...

Comment: 1) Don't use sysprep. 2) Read this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962112.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 3) Always make a full binary image of a drive when trying to recover data from it, before doing ANYTHING else. 4) At least try booting it with the hardware mismatch, Windows is pretty good at dealing with it these days. As long as it's Intel -> Intel or AMD -> AMD it should work - I've moved a drive out of a 2008 X58 desktop into a 2011 QM67 laptop and then 2016 Z170 Intel desktop board - booted first time every time.